# Command: php artisan schedule:run Not Working for 2nd?

Tags: php, laravel, schedule, laravel-artisan

I try to send mail to my gmail every minute.

My crontab: [From here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling)

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php path/artisan scheduled:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then I set function Schedule in /App/Console/Kernel.php:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->hourly();        
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $email = "My_Gmail_Receive";            
        $msg = 'example_view';
        $data = [];
        Mail::send($msg, $data, function($message) use($email)
        {
            $message->from('My_Gmail_Send', 'Hello');

            $message->to($email)->subject('Please checkout!');
        });
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Finnaly, I running: `$ php artisan schedule:run`

Then "My_Gmail_Receive" receive a corresponding message. But it not working automatic everyMinute().( It just work 1 time when I run `$ php artisan schedule:run`)

What wrong with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crontab has a spelling error: it's `schedule:run`, not `scheduled:run`. I also assume that `path/artisan` isn't actually in your crontab, but rather the actual path to artisan. :)

Comment: My crontab: * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Oh, so you're on a mac? OSX doesn't use crontab the way linux does. Also, you have an extra `1` in that line. I'd look at another solution.

Comment: Wait. It work :). It's my mistake: schedule:run and scheduled:run. I will test it with public server. Thank you so much. It make me than 2 hour to fix.

Comment: The last question? How to stop it? :( .

Comment: Ah, I see. :) Glad you got it working. What do you mean stop it? You can't stop a cronjob other than by removing it from cron - or by not doing it `everyMinute()`.